# Should I use self or this in service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have seen usage of `this` as the shared worker context, but also `self` in other documentations.

Which one should I use ?

Comment: Could you show us a code snippet? In javascript to reffer to the current context you use `this` keyword.

Comment: I believe `self` is the reserved keyword to designate the worker (local global) scope within the worker itself. Basically for that reason only people should stop using `self` as a temporary reference to `this` in proper JS as it might become confusing.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini see https://serviceworke.rs/

Comment: Ok, I got, I'm not an expert of this lib, from the examples I saw you should use `self`. Anyway in Javascript you should always be careful on using `this` as it could be very different from what you think it should be.

Comment: What about **globalThis** ?

Comment: globalThis did not exist when I asked, but now I think it can be used as well.

Comment: I would use `self`. But `this` also works if you know what you're doing (if you're in global scope for example, or your function is a method on the global object, or you're not in strict mode and your function wasn't called with `new` or `.call` or `.bind` or `.apply`)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`self` is guaranteed to point to the [ServiceWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) in which you can find properties such as [`clients`, `registration` or `caches` and a variety of event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope#Properties). In the other hand, `this` obeys the same rules about dynamic binding as in the rest of the JavaScript environment. It does not matter always you remember this but my advice is to use `self` when you want to refer the global context specifically.